# Resolving entities with Spring Data Neo4j returns wrong entity types

Tags: spring, neo4j, nosql, spring-data-neo4j

I'm experiencing some strange behavior when I'm looking up node entities with Spring Data Neo4j (SDN). If I use GraphRepository.findOne(long) it will return an entity with that identifier even though the entity is not of the same type.

This is what my (very) simplified entity structure looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
protected abstract class BaseEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @RelatedTo(type = RelationType.ENTITY_AUDIT)
    private Audit audit;

}

@NodeEntity
public final class Person extends BaseEntity {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    private String firstName;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    private String lastName;

}

@NodeEntity
public class Audit extends BaseEntity {

    @RelatedTo(type = RelationType.ENTITY_AUDIT, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private BaseEntity parent;

    private Long date;

    private String user;

}
```

For every entity type, I've created repositories like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {}

@Repository
public interface AuditRepository extends GraphRepository<Audit> {}
```

I've got an abstract base class for my service layer classes. That is what they roughly look like:

```
public abstract class MyServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements MyService<T> {

    private GraphRepository<T> repository;

    public MyServiceImpl(final GraphRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public T read(final Long identifier) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return repository.findOne(identifier);
    }

    @Override   
    public T create(final T entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

}

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl extends MyServiceImpl<Person> implements PersonService {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonServiceImpl(final PersonRepository personRepository) {
        super(personRepository);
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

}
```

When I execute the following code, the result is not as expected:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Test");
person.setLastName("Person");
personService.create(person);
// suppose the person identifier is 1L
final Audit audit = auditRepository.findOne(1L);
```

You'd expect that the AuditRepository would return null, but this in not the case. Instead, it returns an Audit with identifier 1L and null in all of its properties. It seems that as long as there's a node that corresponds to a given identifier, it will be returned, no mather what its type is. If Person and Audit would have had matching property names, they would contain their values too... Is all this expected behavior, or am I missing something?

For now, I've solved this problem with the code below, where I do the type check myself.

```
public abstract class MyServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements MyService<T> {

    private GraphRepository<T> repository;

    public MyServiceImpl(final GraphRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public T read(final Long identifier) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return get(identifier);
    }

    protected T get(final Long identifier) throws EntityNotFoundException {     
        final T entity = repository.findOne(identifier);
        final Class<T> type = getServiceType();
        if (entity == null || !(type.equals(repository.getStoredJavaType(entity)))) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(type, identifier);
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Class<T> getServiceType() {
         return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                 .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

}
```

If you need more configuration, please let me know.

My framework versions are:

```
<spring.version>3.2.0.RC1</spring.version>
<neo4j.version>1.8</neo4j.version>
<spring.data.neo4j.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.data.neo4j.version>
```

Comment: thank you @tstorms, this post and your workaround were very helpful to me when dealing with this bug.

Comment: Just a short question: should the '@Autowired` annotation of `PersonServiceImpl` be on `PersonRepository` field rather than the constructor?

Comment: No, why? I chose constructor injection instead of field injection. A very interesting read about why field injection can be "evil": http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/.

Answer (score 2):

we had that behavior before that it failed on the wrong entity type being returned, we changed that behavior so that the type you provide is used to automatically project the node to.

```
public <S extends PropertyContainer, T> T createEntityFromStoredType(S state, MappingPolicy mappingPolicy) {..}
```

template. createEntityFromStoredType(node, null) will get you the object with the stored state.

```
public Class getStoredJavaType(Object entity) {}
```

gives you the stored class for a node or relationship (or entity)

We had a discussion of changing the behavior back and failing esp. in Repositories.

The question is, what should happen then? An Exception? A Null result? ...

In general if you provide a raw node-id that is valid, returning an error or Null doesn't seem to be like a correct answer either?

Comment: In my workaround, I throw an exception when an entity of a wrong type is returned. To me, that does feel natural. Maybe it's just a matter of taste? Although changing back the behavior would be ideal for my project, wouldn't that break many production environments?

Comment: I would agree that an exception should be thrown when a node with the id is found, but it is not of the excepted type. Why's that? I use annotations on properties of the expected type. An exception is thrown because expected properties are not found when the object is initialized. An exception from the repository would be cleaner in that case IMHO.

Comment: To satisfy most usage scenarios: Maybe the desired behaviour should be configurable.

Comment: That would indeed be a great addition! @Michael, what do you think?

Comment: I want to weigh in here and say that: on repository level i feel that it is unacceptable that PersonRepository.find(123L) returns anything at all if there is no person with id 123L. I feel like the only correct behavior would be throw an ObjectNotFoundException. I also feel that the current behavior was very implicit and not well documented whicch in turn caused me to introduce a bug into my code.

Comment: I do agree with @Hendrik. Another really strange example is that findAll returns all nodes of the repository type, but you can use findOne on the same repository to return an (empty) instance using an Id that is not returned in findAll. That does not seem to make sense. 

Returning Null for findOne when an Id of another entity type than the repository is used seems the way to go. That is already what happens when you use an Id that does not exist in the repository. Besides, all other repository methods respects the repository type why findOne would not?

Comment: I have this query that is supposed to return a list of documents but since I start with a certain node id it also throws an exception: @Query("START v=node({0}) match (d:Document)-[:VISIT]->(v) RETURN d"). So it is wrong to throw exception.